# Silex assets files

Tags: html, css, symfony, silex

I have problem with add CSS files to my project. I holding everything that i can include as stylesheet in this tree:

[image: Tree of files]

In my layout.twig (this is base twig file for rest), i have this line

```
<link href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/Assets/Css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It`s not working correctly. First thing is that Silex use my localhost:8080/Assets/Css/main.css as failed route.
In source of my web page i can see that my tree Assets --> Css is merged into one route called "Assets/Css":
[image: path in source page]

I have one simple question. HOW to include correctly my CSS/JS/IMG files. Thank you for every kind of help.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Assets` folder seems to not be accessible via web, so you need to move the assets (and likely also your `.htaccess` file) to inside your publicly accessible folder. Judging from the screenshot, that would be `web/`. Either that, or you need to map a URL (or subdomain) in your server config to point at the `Assets`-folder.

Comment: I moved my folder to /web/Assets... I have a same problem like before. You said about map a URL. You mean - modify .htaccess file, right?

Comment: Remapping the URL should not be necessary as long as the `Assets` folder is publicly available in the `web/` directory. Try placing a normal HTML file (like `hello.html` or something) in your `web` folder, and go to `http://localhost:8080/hello.html`. If that works, try placing it inside `/web/Assets/`, and go to `http://localhost:8080/Assets/hello.html`. If that doesn't work, something else is wrong with your server setup. Also: try using consistent lowercase for public folders, to eliminate case-sensitive errors — rename `web/Assets/` to `web/assets/`.

Comment: I have error when i trying to get http://localhost:8080/hello.html 
http://prntscr.com/a0zrt2

Comment: In that case, I think you need to make sure a) that you have an `.htaccess` file inside the public directory (which should be `web/`) and b) that it looks something like this: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

Comment: Ok fine, i am on good way (thanks to you) because i can see other folders under my `web/` directory. But now, i can not access to my routes like this: `http://localhost:8080/home` I need to add "web" directory in URL `http://localhost:8080/web/home` . However i add this line in my .htaccess `RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]` and i got error with code 500.

Comment: You should have the server point to the `web/` directory, not the root directory. Nothing above `web/` should be accessible to the browser.

Comment: THANK YOU! It was my huge mistake. I had point to root directory, not to `web/`. Everything is working now!

Answer (score 1):

If your assets are hosted under a different host, you might want to abstract the path by defining a Silex parameter:

$app['asset_path'] = 'http://assets.examples.com';

Using it in a template is as easy as before:

{{ app.asset_path }}/css/styles.css

Comment: It`s not hosted under different host, and i even tried this before. Same situation - path to css is merged into on route. Like on screenshot upper.